# convergence radius of $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}(\sqrt{ 4^n +3^n}＋ (-1)^n\sqrt{ 4^n-3^n})x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series

I want to know the convergence radius of $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}(\sqrt{ 4^n +3^n}＋(-1)^n\sqrt{ 4^n-3^n})x^n$.

Firstly, I tired to calculate $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k+1}}\right|$,but I noticed this series does not converse.So we should try to use another test to check the convergence.

Thank you in advance, my teachers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the root test, which says the radius of convergence is always $\frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}$ where $a_n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$. This works even if this root doesn't actually converge to one number.

Now it's reasonable to expect that $|a_{2n}|^{1/(2n)}$ and $|a_{2n+1}|^{1/(2n+1)}$ each converge here. So you're basically looking at $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \sqrt{4^n+3^n}+\sqrt{4^n-3^n} \right )^{1/n}$ (after changing variables to $2n$) and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \sqrt{4^n+3^n}-\sqrt{4^n-3^n} \right )^{1/n}$ (after changing variables to $2n+1$). The former limit is the bigger one, which is the one that matters for the limsup, and it is $2$. So the radius of convergence is $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, how to calculate the limp of the former one?

Comment: @川村はるか $\sqrt{4^n+3^n}+\sqrt{4^n-3^n}=2^n \left ( \sqrt{1+(3/4)^n} + \sqrt{1-(3/4)^n} \right )$ so that to the $1/n$ is like $2$ times a bounded thing to the $1/n$ so it goes to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your principal terms are positive.

$$ a_n = 4^{n/2} x^n(1+\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{3^n}{4^n}-\dfrac{1}{8}\dfrac{9^n}{16^n}+(-1)^n(1-\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{3^n}{4^n}+\dfrac{1}{8}\dfrac{9^n}{16^n}) + o(\dfrac{x^n9^n}{16^n})) $$

$$a_{2n}= 2  \times4^{n}x^{2n}+o(2 \times 4^{2n}x^{2n})$$
$$a_{2n+1}=x^{2n+1}3^{2n+1} +o(x^{2n+1}3^{2n+1} ) $$

Both series have to converge :

Hence

$$ R=\min(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{2}) =\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{4^{2n}+3^{2n}}+\sqrt{4^{2n}-3^{2n}}=2 \cdot 4^n + o(1)$, which is the coefficient of $x^{2n}$, which winds up with a radius of convergence of $1/2$ for the sum of the even terms.

Comment: Yes thanks for correction.

Comment: But certainly the odd terms behave better than the even terms...indeed $\sqrt{4^n+3^n}-\sqrt{4^n-3^n} \to 0$...

Answer (score 0):

$${\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}} \left(\sqrt{ \; \; 1 \; \; + \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \; \; \; } \; \;＋ \;(-1)^n \;\sqrt{ \; \; 1 \; \; - \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^n \; \; \; } \; \;\right)(2x)^n$$.

Comment: Thank you ! How can I proceed from here?From here, how can I calculate the convergence radius?